# Почему программа выводит лишние символы?

Tags: c, инспекция-кода

Код,который "реверсит" строку, как только пользователь нажал на ENTER:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 40000
char reverse(char string[]);

int main()
{
    int c;
    char string[MAXLINE];

    for (int i = 0; i <= MAXLINE; ++i)
        string[i] = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        string[i] = c;
        ++i;
        if (c == '\n'){
            for (int e = i; e >= 0; --e)
                putchar(string[e]);

            char string[MAXLINE];
            for (int i = 0; i <= MAXLINE + 1; ++i)
                string[i] = 0;

            i = 0;
            putchar('\n');
        }

    }

}
```

Вот что выводит:

```
timur@timur:~/Documents/C/Part_1$ ./ex_1_19
hello world            #ввод данных + ENTER
                       #почему пустая строка?
dlrow olleh            #вывод данных (правильно)
                       #просит еще раз что-то ввести. Я нажимаю ENTER
e                      #почему она выводит???
                       #странная пустая строка
                       #ввожу enter
e                      #почему она выводит???
                       #странная пустая строка
                       #ввожу enter
e                      #почему она выводит???
                       #странная пустая строка
hello world            #ввод данных
                       #странная пустая строка
dlrow olleh            #вывод
good bye               #ввод
l                      #странная строка
eyb doog               #вывод
f*cking C              #ввод
d                      #странная строка
C gnikc*f              #вывод
```

Как реализовать функцию reverse массива?

Answer (score 1):

Вы, наверное, хотели вот это?

```
int main()
{
    int c;
    char string[MAXLINE] = "";
    int i = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        string[i] = c;
        ++i;
        if (c == '\n'){
            for (int e = i-2; e >= 0; --e)
                putchar(string[e]);
            i = 0;
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Посмотрите, в чем отличие - и все станет понятно...

Comment: почему i-2, а не i-1?

Comment: Чтобы не выводить `\n` - зачем?

Comment: получается text\n\0?

Comment: Вы выводите посимвольно - вам `\0` *вообще не нужен*. Вот вы ввели, скажем, `hello\n` - после ввода у вас `i == 6`. А выводить вам надо `olleh` - т.е. символы номер 4,3,2,1,0.

Answer (score 0):

Автор выше хоть и указал на проблему но не описал её. Проблема в этом участке кода, а именно в "char string[MAXLINE];"

```
      for (int e = i; e >= 0; --e)
            putchar(string[e]);

        char string[MAXLINE];
        for (int i = 0; i <= MAXLINE + 1; ++i)
            string[i] = 0;
```

Вы зачем-то заново объявляете строку, причем это будет уже другая строка, ее видно только внутри while. Читайте про области видимости переменных, тут локальная(только что объявленная) доминирует, и вы обнуляете её, а не ту, где к вас лежит старая строка. Если убрать эту строку, то всё будет работать, а вообще, символ можно обнулять сразу, после его вывода(тоже как у автора выше).